# Identify specfic element in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a table with a list of user information in it. And each row consists of an update icon and a delete icon. The particular user record must get deleted when clicked on a delete icon. The rows in the table are generated dynamically. So how can i identify which user's delete icon has been clicked? All of this is in a `ejs` file.

```
<tbody>
     <% for(var item in user) { %>
     <% console.log(user); %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= user[item].id %></td>
                <td><%= user[item].firstName %></td>
                <td><%= user[item].lastName %></td>
                <td><%= user[item].emailId %></td>
            <td>
            <span onclick="editUser()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </td>
            </tr>
      <% }%>
</tbody>
```

I have the user id in the first column. how can i identify the which user's delete icon has been clicked? I want to delete the user information in `db` and reflect it in here without reloading the page(Using Ajax).

Comment: you can either pass the id as a parameter or pass `this` to the `editUser()` function (`onclick="editUser(this)"`) and then inside the function you can get the id: `function editUser(el) { id = el.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].innerHTML; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the work mostly done.  All you need to do is figure out which user needs to be edited, and which needs to be deleted.  I have modified your HTML to allow for both.  Now the "editUser()" method and the new "deleteUser()" method take "id" as a parameter.

```
<tbody>
 <% for(var item in user) { %>
 <% console.log(user); %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= user[item].id %></td>
            <td><%= user[item].firstName %></td>
            <td><%= user[item].lastName %></td>
            <td><%= user[item].emailId %></td>
        <td>
        <span onclick="editUser(<%= user[item].id %>)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        <span onclick="deleteUser(<%= user[item].id %>)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
        </tr>
 <% }%>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table id="userstable">
<tbody>
     <% for(var item in user) { %>
     <% console.log(user); %>
            <tr>
                <td class="id"><%= user[item].id %></td>
                <td><%= user[item].firstName %></td>
                <td><%= user[item].lastName %></td>
                <td><%= user[item].emailId %></td>
            <td>
            <span onclick="editUser()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </td>
            </tr>
      <% }%>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $("#userstable .glyphicon-remove").on("click", function(e){
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.id").text();
    alert( id );
    //Use id here to make ajax call as you desire
  });//click
</script>
```